# Customizing editor widget for feature layer

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, feature-layer, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

Here is the code for the editor widget:

```
<esri:EditorWidget x:Name="MyEditorWidget" Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}" 
                                      Width="300" 
                                      AutoSelect="False"
                                      GeometryServiceUrl="http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer"
                                      ShowAttributesOnAdd="True"  />
```

This is **[provided by Esri](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_editing_widget.html)**. Some of these buttons have no use for our clients.

Is there any possible way to get rid of them?

Also, can I use some of the features from the editor without actually having the widget, such as the Add?

I have not seen any documentation for this.

Here is a picture of what the editor widget looks like:

[image]

The only buttons I am interested in are the Save Edits, Add, and Clear Selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation of ESRI, there is no way to select which buttons should appear, furthermore they states ["If you do not use the Editor Widget, you need to code your own editing experience."](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#//01700000004q000000) I was digging in the technical documentation for that control....and I couldn't find a way to do it. :(

**New information:**

According to a blog from may 20 of 2010 you cna modify the existing controls using Expression blend. Using this tool you can modify the look and feel of the controls, using templates, this options does no modify the behaviors, maybe you should try  it :

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/20/use-control-templates-to-customize-the-look-and-feel-of-arcgis-controls/

Comment: Well that is just a bummer... And there is no code that I can find anywhere that shows how to create your own. I just want them to be able to add points...

Comment: Try the information in this page http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/How_to_add_features_to_a_graphics_layer/01700000008q000000/

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/How_to_edit_a_local_feature_layer/01700000004p000000/

Comment: Making some research there is ablog that maybe will help you: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/20/use-control-templates-to-customize-the-look-and-feel-of-arcgis-controls/